# Multiple collection join/concat query with Mongoose similar to union query in SQL

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 4 collection named students, teachers, stuffs and managers with same mongoose schema.

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    email: String
})
```

how can I retrieve all the students, stuffs, managers and teachers where their age>=25 within one query?
data should be look like concatenated as in SQL performs in union query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/). Specify the age >= 25 criteria in `pipeline`.

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_njUnwlSezg) for your reference.